# arraylist not printing successfully

Tags: java, arraylist

i am trying to print object of a class using arraylist, but why I am getting this output

```
list is Test@27b4de03
list is Test@27b4de03
```

this is the way I am trying to iterate arraylist

```
for (int q=0;q<list.size();q++){
System.out.println("list is "+list.get(q));
}
```

and that is my main method where I am calling method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
Test t=new Test ();
ArrayList<Test> list=new ArrayList<Test>();   
     
System.out.println("size"+list.size());
        
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String b = "";
int count = 0;        
    
for (int i = 0; b != "stop"; i++) {
    System.out.print("==> ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    count++;
    if (input.equals("stop")) {
        b = "stop";
    }    
    else {
        String temp = "";
        char d;
        String c="";
        char cd=' ';
        char ab=' ';
        for (i = 0; i < input.length()&& c!="comment"; i++) {            
                               
            if (ab=='s') {
                if (input.charAt(i)=='\"') {
                    temp=temp+"\"";
                    t. word(temp,count,vp,cp);
                    list.add(t);
                    temp="";
                    ab=' ';
                }
                else {
                    temp=temp+input.charAt(i);
                }
            }
```

and that is my word method where I am passing the word which I get I get from another method

```
void word(String word ,int count,String cp,String vp) {
    switch (word) {

        case "int":
        case "char":
        case "float":
        case "string":
        case "boolean":

            cp="datatype";
            vp=word;
            line=count;
            System.out.println("Token: [ CP: " + cp + ", VP: " + vp + ", Line: " + line + "]");
            break;
```

Comment: basically, that is what you get as result for printing an instance of a class for which there is no implementation of toString, so that of Object is used

Comment: Can u post the test class implementation here? Also as suggested by @stultuske, read through `toString() override` in Java

Answer (score 0):

Override the toString method of the Object class. example:

```
public class Employee {
    private String Name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "Name='" + Name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList();

        list.add(new Employee("Bert"));
        list.add(new Employee("Ernie"));
        for (int q=0;q<list.size();q++){
            System.out.println("list is "+list.get(q));
        }
        //alternate shorter for each for java 8+
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }


}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html